# how can i write a program which starts before logging on to windows?

Tags: windows, startup

how can i write a program which starts before logging on to windows?!

Comment: Your request is rather vague. Are you talking about a Windows service or an actual application?

Comment: I think as "Pablo Santa Cruz" said, it should be a windows service...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to write a [Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412(VS.80).aspx).